# How to extract/inject ID3 tags via bash?

Tags: bash, id3

I have a huge collection of MP3 files that have ID3 metadata. Is it possible to extract existing tags and images to plain text (e.g. JSON, XML)? Can I inject from plain text to MP3 file? How can I do that only via-command-line

Answer (score 4):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install eyeD3
```

[eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/) is a terminal program to display and manipulate id3-tags on the command-line.
A command-line editor to add/edit/remove ID3-tags on mp3 files. It supports version 1.0,1.1,2.3 and 2.4 of the ID3 standard.  Additionally it displays several information about the file such as length and bitrate from an MP3 file.

A web search using the search terms `bash script eyeD3` will bring up examples of bash scripts using eyeD3 designed to do several different kinds of tasks such as reading mp3 tags, writing mp3 tags, read/write ID3V1 (ID3 version 1) tags, and read/write ID3V2 (ID3 version 2) tags.

Comment: I've found some scripts with eyeD3, but many of them are intended to edit/remove tags, not to read. :(
Also, did not see anything about "exotic" tags, like that put by iTunes for mark podcast files.

Comment: For "exotic" tags I like MP3 Diags, but it is a GUI application. For scripts for just reading tags you can also use mp3info which has both GUI and command line versions.

Comment: Addendum: the version in Ubuntu repository (0.6.*) don't support plugins. To get the 0.7.* version, you need to use `sudo pip install eyeD3`.

Comment: For further clarification. MP3 Diags is a difficult application to use, but the reason why I sometimes use it anyway is that it can remove "stubborn" tags that the other applications can't remove as well as unwanted lyrics and album cover art.